# Hide past times in day's dropdown

Tags: php

I have a dropdown menu that lists all times from 9am until 7:30pm.

If it's 1pm, I'd like to only show options such as 1:30pm, 2pm and so on.

How do I achieve this with my current code?

```
 // time.php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$now = date("H:i");
$start = "05:00";
$end = "19:30";

$tStart = strtotime() > strtotime($start) ? strtotime() : strtotime($start);

$tNow = $tStart;
$tEnd = strtotime($end);

echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
while($tNow <= $tEnd){
    echo '<option value="'.date("H:i:s",$tNow).'">'.date("H:i:s",$tNow).'</option>';
    $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Did you try an add a if()?

Comment: what if the time is 1:20 you want to start at 1:30 or 1:20? Secondly, when it is 1:50 you would like to start at 2:00 or 1:50?

Comment: Good question. It should only be :30 :00, never :20, :10:, :40 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the time is 1:20 you want to start at 1:30 or 1:20? Secondly, when it is 1:50 you would like to start at 2:00 or 1:50? I assumed you want to start at 1:30 and 2:00 in these two examples:

```
<?php
$hour = date('H');
$min = date('i');
echo 'Current time '.$hour.':'.$min;
if($min <=30){
  $min = '30';
} else {
  $min= '00';
  $hour +=1;
  if($hour > 23){
    $hour ='00';
  }
}
$start = $hour.':'.$min;
echo 'Modified time '.$start;
$end = "19:30";

$tStart = strtotime($start);
$tEnd = strtotime($end);
$tNow = $tStart;
echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
while($tNow <= $tEnd){
    echo '<option value="'.date("H:i:s",$tNow).'">'.date("H:i:s",$tNow).'</option>';
    $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Fantastic, @fiveelements. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know it worked for now. If needed please change the if-else condition at the top as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your start time if it's already past 9:

```
<?php

 // time.php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$start = "05:00";
$end = "19:30";

$now = time();
// Normalize Now to next 1/2 hour
$now = ($now - ($now % 1800)) + 1800;

$tStart = $now > strtotime($start) ? $now : strtotime($start);
$tEnd = strtotime($end);

echo '<select name="schedule_time">' . PHP_EOL;
while($tStart <= $tEnd){
    echo '<option value="'.date("H:i:s",$tStart).'">'.date("H:i:s",$tStart).'</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    $tStart+= 1800;
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Hi, I've revised my code above, but it's still showing all available dropdown options, even those in the past.

Comment: You had some slight variations, so I integrated the idea into your code.